# Sharepoint 2016 and Nintex Workflows Scheduler never runs

Tags: sharepoint, nintex-workflow, sharepoint-2016

The Nintex Workflow Scheduler will not run when attempting to start it from central administration. I have contacted Nintex multiple times about the issue in order to get this to run but without success, so I am hoping to reach out to others who might know more. Here is the background and already attempted fixes:

Our topology includes 2 wfe, 2 apps, 1 sql, and 1 workflow server. The wfe are not load balanced but we do have Nintex Licenses for both servers.

I have followed these steps provided by Nintex:

Enable the AllowServiceJobs property on the timer instance for the APP, WFE and Search Server 
The following command should be run on each of the aforementioned servers.

(Get-SPFarm).TimerService.Instances | ?{$_.Server.Name -eq $env:COMPUTERNAME} | %{[Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPTimerServiceInstance].GetMember("set_AllowServiceJobs", [Enum]::GetValues([System.Reflection.BindingFlags])).Invoke($_,$true) }

2. Update the timer service instances

Get-SPServiceInstance -All | ?{$*.TypeName -match "Foundation Timer"} | %{$*.Update()}

3. Restart the timer service instances

Get-SPServiceInstance -All | ?{$*.TypeName -match "Foundation Timer"} | %{$*.Server.Name;$*.Stop();sleep 5;$*.Start();sleep 5;"Done"}

Also followed this documentation: https://community.nintex.com/docs/DOC-1254-scheduled-workflows-and-the-nintex-workflow-scheduler-timer-job

and this: https://support.nintex.com/SharePoint/Workflow/2016/Scheduler_Job_Does_Not_Run_After_Upgrading_Nintex_Workflow_for_SharePoint_2016

I also bounced the entire farm. 
I have also followed the additional information suggested by Nintex:

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION

If the issue remains unresolved, :
1. Ensure only ONE Nintex Scheduler Job exists in the farm & it is associated to the Central Administration web app.
2. Run the timer Job in Central Administration and via PowerShell.
3. Provide the ULS logs after performing the above recommended actions.

Are there any other suggestions on how I can get the Nintex Scheduled workflows to run on my environment?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the workflow scheduler timer job is running only on WFE Servers.

I faced this kind of issue when the scheduler timer job was configured to run on APP server. I changed it to WFE server and restarted the timer services. It then started working.